# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 failed

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

A notification came up:

```
Cannot upgrade secure boot enforcement policy due to unsigned kernels
Your system has UEFI secure boot enabled firmware, and the following kernels present on your system are unsigned:
4.4.0-134-generic
The kernels cannot be verified under secure boot. To ensure your system remains bootable, GRUB will not be upgraded on your disk until these kernels are removed or replaced with signed kernels.
```

and the upgrade has stopped. Can someone please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn off secure boot in your BIOS/UEFI Settings and let the unsigned packages upgrade, or install the linux-signed-generic, shim-signed, grub-efi-amd64-signed, and fwupdate-signed on your 16.04 system and upgrade with secure boot.

---

The upgrade should work if you turn off secure boot and try again.
To install the packages, start a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t ) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install  linux-signed-generic shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed fwupdate-signed
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how to install the linux-signed-generic, shim-signed, grub-efi-amd64-signed, and fwupdate-signed, or direct me to a page which will give me the information. Thanks again for answering.

Comment: ps.. if I reboot my system now and change the bios setting will the upgrade still work ?

Comment: Hey, thank you, "ubfan1" I followed your advice and changed the bios setting and the upgrade went through, everything is working just fine. Thanks again for your advice, much appreciated.

Comment: You can click on the accept answer icon and that marks this as solved.

Comment: You answer helps, Thanks. After disabling secure boot and restart and then install the packages you presented, the upgrade finishes. Now can I enable security boot again or I should keep it disabled in order to use ubuntu 18

Comment: @lui-sha Easy to just enable it and see.  Problems range from having proprietary drivers (Nvidia...), to vendor requirements for specific names on the bootloaders.  Search this site for solutions to those problems if you want.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread - Do I disable UEFI, then install those packages and re-enable it? Or do I have to keep UEFI disabled?

Comment: @hosh-sadiq UEFI remains on at all times.  Secure boot would have to be off to boot an unsigned kernel, or a signed kernel with unsigned drivers for hardware like Nvidia video.

Comment: Aah! So the only way to get rid of that warning is to actually sign the kernel? Okay! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running uname -r should state 18.04 after a reboot. If reboot fails, go into recovery mode and repair install (dpkg) then boot normally.

After booting, install linux-generic which should install the latest (4.15) kernel
Reboot and at the grub menu, select advanced and boot into the 4.15 kernel. 
Then run sudo apt-get install  linux-signed-generic shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed fwupdate-signed - which should now install without errors

Then sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and I solved it recently by signing the kernel.
**Warning: replacing the unsigned kernel is dangers; any tiny mistakes may cause kernel panic.** Please be aware of what you are doing.

#### Acknowledgment

Thanks to following two posts I leaned how to sign a kernel to solve this problem, you can refer to them for more details.

https://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2019/04/23/fixing-grub-error-about-unsigned-kernel-in-ubuntu/
https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot

My notes for solving this problem are listed below.

### Fixing grub error about unsigned kernel in Ubuntu

ERROR INFO:

```
Cannot upgrade Secure Boot enforcement policy due to unsigned kernels

Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled in firmware, and the following kernels present on your system are unsigned:

 4.18.20-041820-generic

These kernels cannot be verified under Secure Boot. To ensure your system remains bootable, GRUB will not be upgraded on your disk until these kernels are removed or replaced with signed kernels.
```

#### Certificates in shim

- cd to a directory you want to save the Certificates
- `vim openssl.cnf` to create a new file
- input following contents in the file (modify the req_distinguished_name info if you like, it is ok to left it as it is).

```
# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME                    = .
RANDFILE                = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
[ req ]
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions         = v3
string_mask             = utf8only
prompt                  = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName             = CA
stateOrProvinceName     = Quebec
localityName            = Montreal
0.organizationName      = cyphermox
commonName              = Secure Boot Signing
emailAddress            = example@example.com

[ v3 ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:FALSE
extendedKeyUsage        = codeSigning,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6
nsComment               = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
```

- creat the private and public keys

```
openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf \
        -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -nodes -days 36500 -outform DER \
        -keyout "MOK.priv" \
        -out "MOK.der"
```

#### Enrolling the key

To enroll a key, use the mokutil command:

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

Follow the prompts to enter a password that will be used to make sure you really do want to enroll the key in a minute.

Once this is done, **reboot**. Just before loading GRUB, shim will show a blue screen (which is actually another piece of the shim project called “MokManager”). use that screen to select “Enroll MOK” and follow the menus to finish the enrolling process. You can also look at some of the properties of the key you’re trying to add, just to make sure it’s indeed the right one using “View key”. MokManager will ask you for the password we typed in earlier when running mokutil; and will save the key, and we’ll reboot again.

#### sign a custom kernel you want to have loaded by shim

- convert the certificate we created earlier into PEM:

```
openssl x509 -in MOK.der -inform DER -outform PEM -out MOK.pem
```

- **back up** the original vmlinuz file (e.g., vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic)

```
sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic ./
```

- sign the kernel with following command (modify the kernel name accordingly)

```
sudo sbsign --key MOK.priv --cert MOK.pem /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic --output vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic.signed
```

- move the signed kernel to the `/boot/` directory (**and make sure the signed kernel has the same name as the original one**)

```
sudo mv vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic.signed /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5-041805-generic
```

- rebuild grub menus with following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

This command causes grub to rebuild its menus. **Make sure for each grub menu item (especially the signed one), there is a `linux ...` line and a `initrd ....` line.** Otherwise you may encounter "kernel panic" next time you reboot the system.

Rebuilding grub menu is probably not strictly necessary because I didn’t actually add any new kernels to /boot/, but it was worth running to make sure there weren’t any errors.

- This fixes the installation of the package that was broken. If all goes according to plan, it should no longer show an error.

```
sudo dpkg --configure grub-efi-amd64-signed
```